# Having a hard time identifying this component; maybe the logo can help

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, identification, surface-mount, soic

Does anyone have any idea what this part Q6 is? It appears to be some type of SOIC 8 FET.

[image: PCB.]

Logo on the device:
[image: Logo.]

Comment: General Semiconductors Industries Inc

Answer (score 14):

It very much appears to be a 4601 dual MOSFET.

The "Q" in "Q6" next to the component indicates it is a transistor device.

A single MOSFET would have four pins on one side connected together, and three pins on the other side connected together, leaving a single pin for the gate. The device shown has wide tracks (for low resistance) connecting two pairs of two pins on one side, so I guessed it was a dual MOSFET, which is confirmed as a strong possibility by searching for "4601 dual mosfet".

The logo looks like the one for Sinopower: [SM4601CSK datasheet](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/1138937/SINOPWER/SM4601CSKC-TRG.html).